# Segmented LRU Cache in Java

Tags: java, caching, data-structures

I have to implement a segmented LRU cache in Java. Not able to understand which data structure could be used for it which would be efficient. How can we divide a cache in two segments i.e. probationary and protected?

Here is a link for eviction policy of SLRU cache.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Segmented_LRU_(SLRU)

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you just need two LRU caches. Do you know how to implement an LRU cache? One cache is protected, the other is probationary and you move data between the two according to the rules in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, LRU caches are usually implemented with [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).  This is a hashmap with an internal ordering among nodes.

For a segmented LRU cache, you'll need to make a cache class that includes two of these maps.

For the protected map, use the constructor with `accessOrder = true`, so that every time you access an entry, it will move it to the end of the internal ordering.

You should create subclasses that override the [removeEldestEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry-java.util.Map.Entry-) method to automatically expire entries and move them from the protected to probationary segment when necessary.

Moving cache hits from the probationary map to the protected map will have to be done by your cache class.